# How to create an SLDS Illustration lightning component with svg

Tags: lightning-aura-components, svg

I am trying to create a lightning component that will show an [SLDS illustration](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/illustration/) of missing data:

[image]

when I create my component with the `<svg>` tag I cannot save the component markup:

```
    <svg class="slds-illustration__svg" viewBox="0 0 468 194" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
            <g transform="translate(-67.000000, -112.000000)">
                <g>
                    <g transform="translate(245.000000, 200.000000)" class="slds-illustration__stroke-secondary" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="3">
                        <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M44,17.5 L63,17.5 C62.2789714,12.0723971 64.081543,7.53186978 68.4077148,3.87841797 C73.3754883,-0.195556641 79.2734375,0.717773438 82.440918,2.12353516 C85.6083984,3.52929687 87.9606934,5.46069336 89.5913086,9.10524041 C90.2822266,10.6397351 90.7517904,11.9379883 91,13"></path>
                        <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M83,20.5 C84.0558268,16.8461914 86.2227376,14.4572754 89.5007324,13.333252 C94.4177246,11.6472168 99.0800781,13.8925781 100.942383,16.1518555 C102.804687,18.4111328 103.39502,20.2260742 103.746582,22.1201172 C103.980957,23.3828125 104.06543,24.8427734 104,26.5 C108.141764,26.3313802 110.918945,27.1647135 112.331543,29 C114.040039,31.1936035 114.215332,33.817627 113.593018,35.75 C112.970703,37.682373 110.894531,40.5 107,40.5 L28,40.5"></path>
                        <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M18,27.5 L83.0004985,27.5"></path>
                        <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M0,27.5 L8,27.5"></path>
                    </g>
                    <g transform="translate(135.000000, 152.000000)" class="slds-illustration__stroke-secondary" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="3">
                        <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M44,17.5 L63,17.5 C62.2789714,12.0723971 64.081543,7.53186978 68.4077148,3.87841797 C73.3754883,-0.195556641 79.2734375,0.717773438 82.440918,2.12353516 C85.6083984,3.52929687 87.9606934,5.46069336 89.5913086,9.10524041 C90.2822266,10.6397351 90.7517904,11.9379883 91,13"></path>
                        <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M83,20.5 C84.0558268,16.8461914 86.2227376,14.4572754 89.5007324,13.333252 C94.4177246,11.6472168 99.0800781,13.8925781 100.942383,16.1518555 C102.804687,18.4111328 103.39502,20.2260742 103.746582,22.1201172 C103.980957,23.3828125 104.06543,24.8427734 104,26.5 C108.141764,26.3313802 110.918945,27.1647135 112.331543,29 C114.040039,31.1936035 114.215332,33.817627 113.593018,35.75 C112.970703,37.682373 110.894531,40.5 107,40.5 L28,40.5"></path>
                        <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M18,27.5 L83.0004985,27.5"></path>
                        <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M0,27.5 L8,27.5"></path>
                    </g>
                    <g transform="translate(69.000000, 256.000000)" class="slds-illustration__stroke-secondary" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="3">
                        <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M14,36.5 L464,36.5"></path>
                        <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M0,36.5 L6,36.5"></path>
                        <polyline vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke-linejoin="round" points="234.5 36 279.5 0 313.5 26"></polyline>
                        <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M279.5,1 L279.5,35" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
                        <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M313.5,11 C313.5,20.7437888 313.5,25.7437888 313.5,26 C313.5,25.7437888 313.5,20.7437888 313.5,11 Z" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
                        <polyline vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke-linejoin="round" points="303.5 17 313.5 9 347.5 36"></polyline>
                    </g>
                    <g transform="translate(113.000000, 178.000000)">
                        <g transform="translate(30.000000, 8.000000)" class="slds-illustration__fill-secondary">
                            <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M29.5,60.5 L29.5,12 C29.5,5.372583 34.872583,0 41.5,0 C48.127417,0 53.5,5.372583 53.5,12 L53.5,40.5 L70.5,40.5 L70.5,27 C70.5,23.1340068 73.6340068,20 77.5,20 C81.3659932,20 84.5,23.1340068 84.5,27 L84.5,48.5 C84.5,51.8137085 81.8137085,54.5 78.5,54.5 L53.5,54.5 L53.5,118.5 L29.5,118.5 L29.5,74.5 L6.5,74.5 C3.1862915,74.5 0.5,71.8137085 0.5,68.5 L0.5,39 C0.5,35.1340068 3.63400675,32 7.5,32 C11.3659932,32 14.5,35.1340068 14.5,39 L14.5,60.5 L29.5,60.5 Z"></path>
                        </g>
                        <g transform="translate(59.000000, 7.000000)" fill="#FFFFFF">
                            <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M2,11 C3.65332031,8.49145508 5.65181478,6.77364095 7.9954834,5.84655762 C11.5109863,4.45593262 15.2684326,4.95605469 17.8156738,6.2824707 C20.362915,7.60888672 22.3626709,9.64978027 23.2602539,11.81604 C23.8586426,13.2602132 23.8586426,11.7547201 23.2602539,7.29956055 L19.612793,3.56494141 L13.7923584,0.564331055 L8.765625,1.42663574 L4.67321777,3.19787598 C2.69893392,5.13902708 1.69559733,6.16722532 1.66320801,6.2824707 C1.61462402,6.45533878 0.856079102,9.49145508 0.813964844,9.66003418 C0.785888672,9.77242025 1.18123372,10.2190755 2,11 Z"></path>
                        </g>
                        <g class="slds-illustration__stroke-primary" stroke-width="3">
                            <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M0,126.5 L356,126.5" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
                            <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M362.5,126.5 L372.013149,126.5" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
                            <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M107.5,20 L107.5,28" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
                            <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M113,30.6568542 L118.656854,25" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
                            <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M37.5,32 L37.5,40" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
                            <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M44,42.6568542 L49.6568542,37" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
                            <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M25,42.6568542 L30.6568542,37" stroke-linecap="round" transform="translate(27.828427, 39.828427) scale(-1, 1) translate(-27.828427, -39.828427) "></path>
                            <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M71.5,0 L71.5,8" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
                            <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M79,10.6568542 L84.6568542,5" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
                            <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M58,10.6568542 L63.6568542,5" stroke-linecap="round" transform="translate(60.828427, 7.828427) scale(-1, 1) translate(-60.828427, -7.828427) "></path>
                            <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M59.5,68.5 L59.5,20 C59.5,13.372583 64.872583,8 71.5,8 C78.127417,8 83.5,13.372583 83.5,20 L83.5,48.5 L100.5,48.5 L100.5,35 C100.5,31.1340068 103.634007,28 107.5,28 C111.365993,28 114.5,31.1340068 114.5,35 L114.5,56.5 C114.5,59.8137085 111.813708,62.5 108.5,62.5 L83.5,62.5 L83.5,126.5 L59.5,126.5 L59.5,82.5 L36.5,82.5 C33.1862915,82.5 30.5,79.8137085 30.5,76.5 L30.5,47 C30.5,43.1340068 33.6340068,40 37.5,40 C41.3659932,40 44.5,43.1340068 44.5,47 L44.5,68.5 L59.5,68.5 Z"></path>
                            <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M77,88.5 L92.5,88.5 L92.5,81 C92.5,77.1340068 95.6340068,74 99.5,74 L99.5,74 C103.365993,74 106.5,77.1340068 106.5,81 L106.5,96.5 C106.5,99.8137085 103.813708,102.5 100.5,102.5 L77,102.5"
                                  class="slds-illustration__fill-secondary" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g transform="translate(429.000000, 242.000000)" class="slds-illustration__stroke-secondary" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="3">
                        <g>
                            <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M12.5,4 L12.5,50"></path>
                            <polyline vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke-linejoin="round" points="11 18.5 0.5 18.5 0.5 0"></polyline>
                            <polyline vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke-linejoin="round" points="14 25.5 24.5 25.5 24.5 8"></polyline>
                            <polyline vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke-linejoin="round" points="2.5 31 2.5 38.5 11 38.5"></polyline>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g transform="translate(327.000000, 95.000000)">
                        <g>
                            <circle vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" class="slds-illustration__fill-secondary" cx="64" cy="64" r="23"></circle>
                            <circle vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" class="slds-illustration__stroke-secondary" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-dasharray="135,1,1,18" transform="translate(64.000000, 64.000000) rotate(230.000000) translate(-64.000000, -64.000000) "
                                    cx="64" cy="64" r="45"></circle>
                            <circle vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" class="slds-illustration__stroke-secondary" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-dasharray="107,10" transform="translate(64.000000, 64.000000) rotate(150.000000) translate(-64.000000, -64.000000) "
                                    cx="64" cy="64" r="33"></circle>
                        </g>
                        <g transform="translate(41.000000, 41.000000)" class="slds-illustration__stroke-primary" stroke-width="3">
                            <circle vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" cx="23" cy="23" r="23"></circle>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
    <div class="slds-text-longform">
        <h3 class="slds-text-heading_medium">Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

**QUESTION**:

How do I create an `svg` tag in the lightning markup?

All the [example1](http://hellosnl.blogspot.com/2017/07/including-svg-in-lightning-component.html), [example2](http://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/03/21/use-svg-salesforce-lightning-component/) I can find are very old, and point to opening the SLDS static resource or creating icon to the component - this is not what I am looking for.

Also I found [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/227833/how-to-use-slds-illustration) example which is creating a component from existing svg, but I did not find the missing data ['desert'](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/illustration/#Desert) svg that I want

Comment: Whats the issue with creating a static resource with the svg code for the Desert illustration and then referencing it in the img tag?

Comment: The issue is that it is not a good way to do that, I would expect lightning component support of the svg tag. I do not want to add or update  a static resource to every svg file I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Lightning still doesn't support svg tags.

I haven't tried using `<img src="/path-to-svg.svg"/>` but it should work.  Try saving your code as an svg file, uploading it as a static resource, and referencing it that way.

Comment: Thanks, that works for me and I will use it as long as there is no standard supported solution

Answer (score 2):

For the desert illustration you were looking for:

```
<img src="/img/chatter/Desert.svg" class="slds-illustration__svg" alt="Desert"/>
```