# How to use Illustration from LDS in a Aura Web Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds, svg

I am having a difficult time trying to figure out how to use an illustration inside my Aura Web Component.

I copied all of the data between the `svg` tags for the following: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/illustration/#Desert

I then saved this file as a static resource in my org and called it `noData`.

Next, I created a lightning web component and tried to link to this static resource.

```
<div class="slds-illustration slds-illustration_large" aria-hidden="true">
    <img src="{!$Resource.noData}" alt="" />
    <div class="slds-text-longform">
<h3 class="slds-text-heading_medium">{v.title}</h3>
```

When I try and view the page in my org that is showing this component, there is no image shown.

[image]

The network tab is showing that the resource is loading and the contents of the SVG are shown. The one thing that looks odd to me is when I click the "Preview" tab in the network response, the SVG doesn't appear to look like what I would expect.

Does this have something to do with the SVG referencing classes in the slds? If so, shouldn't those classes exist in lightning by default, not causing any issues like this?

What am I missing? I did look at this [other post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/227833/how-to-use-slds-illustration) and everything looks the same, which is why I feel like I am missing something here.

[image]

**Update:**

From what I can tell, the issue is due to the SVG using classes that reference the lds stylesheet. When I save this image as an SVG and include it in my component, I don't believe it is able to access those style definitions as needed.

To fix this temporarily, I had to embed the style within the SVG it self:

```
<svg class="slds-illustration__svg" viewBox="0 0 468 194" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <style>
    .slds-illustration__stroke-primary {
        stroke: #8cd3f8; 
    }
    .slds-illustration__stroke-secondary {
        stroke: #c2e8ff; 
    }
    .slds-illustration__fill-primary {
        fill: #8cd3f8; 
    }
    .slds-illustration__fill-secondary {
        fill: #c2e8ff; 
    }
    </style>
    ...
```

Comment: Please pay close attention to using the correct tags and names - I spent time answering your question tagged as LWC and stating LWC in the title, now you changed it to Aura (and I deleted my answer). Glad you have corrected it, just would ask you to be accurate when asking a question.

Comment: btw, the terms are Lightning Web Component for LWC plus Aura Component/Lightning Component or in full [Lightning Aura Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/intro_framework.htm). There's no such thing as an Aura Web Component. :)

Answer (score 1):

SVGs are not `img` compatible. They will not display in an `img` tag at all. You have to use `svg` and `use` elements. Further, `svg` is not directly supported in Aura, so you'd have to do dynamic rendering. This is troublesome at best. You'd be better off writing an LWC component and exposing the image that way. I went ahead and made a [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/Fcyit4ra/1/edit) for you to look at. If you really want to do this in pure Aura, you can use the [SVG Icon Helper](https://archive-2_1_4.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/lightning-svg-icon-component-helper) from SLDS. Note that this method is not recommended and should not be considered reliable or future-proofed. Simply use a LWC component instead.